# Should PackageStates.php be under version control?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Whenever we clone a site on a development machine, the `PackageStates.php` will be rewritten shortly after and the order of entries will be all over the place, resulting in tons of changes, even though nothing has actually changed logically.

This brings up the question, should the file actually *be* under version control?

We experimented with ignoring it, but then, when deploying on a new machine, the site will not know which extensions to load. Which suggests to me that it shouldn't be excluded from version control. But then how should the information, which extensions to load, be transferred?

Answer (score 3):

You can include the `PackageStates.php` to your version control.

You also can exclude it from versioning and generate it automatically during deployment process. typo3-console has a command for this:

```
typo3cms install:generatepackagestates
```

In older TYPO3 versions < 9 LTS, you have the option to install extensions based on conditions like context, host, system you can use

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['runtimeActivatedPackages'] = array('extension_builder','devlog');
```

in your `AdditionalConfiguration.php`.

[Article about this topic at typo3blogger.de](http://typo3blogger.de/how-to-install-extensions-only-in-local-development-environment-in-typo3-6-2/)

Comment: Current minor version try to mitigate the problem of reordering by keeping a more stable sorting state.

Comment: with this I get an Exception " Package "phpmyadmin" is already registered" - no phpmyadmin entries in PackageState or LocalConfiguration... I cleared all caches, reinstalled phpmyadmin-ext. but always this error

Comment: Update: since TYPO3 V9 and if you use composer you should exclude PackageStates.php from vc and generate it via cli command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a TYPO3 composer installation, PackageStates.php is automatically generated when running "composer install":

https://docs.typo3.org/p/helhum/typo3-console/6.5/en-us/CommandReference/InstallGeneratepackagestates.html

> Generates and writes `typo3conf/PackageStates.php` file. Goal is to not have this file in version control, but generate it on composer install.

Comment: That depends on helhum/typo3-console being required as well and what is in your composer.json, right? e.g. you must add the install:generatepackagestates in post-dump-autoload. You might want to add a snippet what is in composer.json or in your deployment script.

Comment: That post-install script was setup automatically with a fresh typo3 10.4 composer installation.